# Validation of web service type

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an asp.net mvc application that uses web service. I have various controllers that use the model provided by the web service. The problem is that client and server-side validation cannot be used as the class is not defined in my web application. How should I go about adding validation to this class?

Eg:

```
SomeController {
    someMethod(Service.User u) {
       if (ModelState.isValid) { // always valid as no annotations
```

Comment: Create your own classes with same properties as the service class and add attributes as necessary and use AutoMapper to map property values b/w your class instance and service class instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a View Model and use that:

```
public class UserViewModel()
{
    public int UserId {get;set;}
    //more properties
}
```

Then map it back to the `Service.User` in the controller:

```
public ActionResult SomeMethod(UserViewModel viewModel)
{

}
```